# checkbox event handler throws error for click event in chrome, safari works fine with keyboard event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a list of dynamically created check boxes. when the state of the check box changes, a function is executed. the function runs perfectly in firefox 3.6 perfectly whether the user clicks the check box, or uses keyboard input to change the check box. in chrome or safari, the function executes fine using the keyboard, but errors out with a mouse click. i cannot seem to find why the code acts differently from a mouse click vs a keyboard entry.

here is what i believe is the pertinent code:

```
var q_id = $j('label:contains("SCORP Statewide Need ")').attr('for');
console.log(q_id); //writes out answer id a_721
```

an ajax post will create a list of check boxes:

```
if(found == true){
    output+="<div name='"+q_id+"'><input type='checkbox' name='"+q_id+"' id='"+q_id+"."+i+"' class='check' checked='checked' onChange='saveStateNeed("+q_id+")' value='"+list[i]+"'/>"; 
}else{
    output+="<div name='"+q_id+"'><input type='checkbox' name='"+q_id+"' id='"+q_id+"."+i+"' class='check' onChange='saveStateNeed("+q_id+")' value='"+list[i]+"'/>";
}
output+=" <label name='l_"+q_id+"' for='"+q_id+"."+i+"' id='l_"+q_id+"."+i+"'>"+ list[i] +"</label></div>";
output+="<div class='clearboth'></div><br/>";
$j('##div_'+q_id).append(output);
```

all this is generated perfectly in all browsers.
the error is in the callback saveStateNeed();

```
function saveStateNeed(list){

    console.log('in saveStateNeed');


    console.log(list);// prints out an array of the checkboxes [input#a_721.0.check Non-motorized trails, input#a_721.1.check Sports a...ayfields, input#a_721.2.check Land Acq...projects, input#a_721.3.check Picnicki...cilities, input#a_721.4.check Nature s...wildlife]

           // **in safari i get function()** but it still works with keyboard, fails with click
           // the next assignment $me fails.

    var $me = $j('input [name="'+list+'"]');
    var isChecked = $me.context.activeElement.checked;
    var $value = $me.context.activeElement.attributes['value'].nodeValue;


    console.log($me); out puts the object selected as an expandable firebug object []



    console.log($value); outputs label for object: Picnicking/day use facilities


    console.log(isChecked); outputs true false

    if(isChecked){
    }else{

    }

    $j.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:        });

}
```

this is all kind of convoluted, im just hoping someone knows why i would get a different result from a click then a keyboard entry, when the same code is actually being executed.
i really hope this isnt all too convoluted.
thanks for taking a look at this, and i really appreciate any comments or suggestions you might have.
cheers.

Comment: what error do you get exactly in Chrome/Safari?

Comment: FYI: you may want to remove the console.log statements when testing in other browsers. Some don't support it at all, others only support it when their consoles are visible. Which isn't to suggest I think that's the culprit.

Comment: heh, the actual error i was getting from chrome dev tools is :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined. but again, i only get this from a mouse click, it works fine hitting the space bar to change the checkbox. thanks for looking.

Comment: @tom, thanks,i originally didnt have the console logs there, i stuck them in to see why the code wasnt executing the way it was supposed to, do you have any suggestions on how to see what is going on inside my code with out the logs? i am not as well versed in firebug as i would like, and firebug lite seems to not show as much as the full version i have in ff. thanks again. cheers. the original logs were placed immediately following each assignment, i had stuff changed around a bit as i was trying different option, like passing the actual checkbox id into the callback to try differnt options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have better luck if you attach the checkbox behavior as a delegated event instead of explicit assignment.

It looks like you're using jQuery, so you can do that like so:

```
$j('input.check').live('change', function(event) {
   var jThis = $j(this);
   // grab id from checkbox
   var ID = jThis.attr('id').split('.')[0];
   saveStateNeed(ID, jThis.attr('checked'));
   return true;
});
```

Also: are you certain that the error is in the event handler, and not in the `saveStateNeed` function?

EDIT: Based on your updates, here's what I've got. First, note the minor change to the function above; now it passes two values. Second, if you want to act on a checkbox being toggled, modify `saveStateNeed` to accept two values: an ID and a boolean. Like so:

```
function saveStateNeed(ID, bChecked) {
    console.log('checkbox ' + ID + ' is ' + (bChecked) ? 'checked' : 'not checked');

    if(bChecked) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, they are actually in the saveStateNeed function. my misuse of the terminology. i will see what i can do with this using live. thanks for the time, if this is a solution, i will be sure to return to give credit. thx

Comment: working with this changes the way i get to the function saveStateNeed, but does not change what is going on inside the function. so, in safari, the lines of code
    var isChecked = $me.context.activeElement.checked;
    var $value = $me.context.activeElement.attributes['value'].nodeValue;
both return 'undefined' when the user triggers the change via a mouse click, but they return the proper values when the user triggers the change via the space bar on the keyboard.

Comment: this didnt solve the initial problem, but once i set my code up this way, i just passed $j(this) to the function then was able to use the usual jquery methods and properties to grab all the info i needed once in the function. thanks for the help.